# Load images in React using webpack loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am unable to display images within a React component. After many trials (attempted [this](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/173), [this](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/1493), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570731/react-webpack-module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-you-may-need-an-appro), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848055/image-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077245/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-upload-image-file), [this](https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/images/), [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/55) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader)) and only errors, I am requesting for help. I'm in the development build (not production build).

I still get this error:

```
Module parse failed: /project/src/images/net.png Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Component

```
import thumbnail from '../images/net.png';

<img src={thumbnail}/>
```

Webpack config:

```
devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
],
target: 'web',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: './src'
},
plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /(\.css)$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: { sourcemap: true }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
            include: './src/images',
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: paths.build
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Directory Structure

```
Project
-- src
-----components
-----images
-----index.js
```

How can I display the image ?

Sample code here: [githublink](https://github.com/ubersensei/pluralsight-redux-app-used-to-build-script)
See /src/components/home/HomePage.js

What can I do to see the image on the home page ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this webpack configuration

`{
         test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
           'file-loader'
         ]
       }`

Comment: then will you try please  changing your image to another one to be sure that the image is not damaged or corrupted.

Comment: I think something with your dev environment. Have you tried to clear the cache . Or use image with different format not png.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `url-loader` instead.

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 25000 // Max file size = 25kb
      }
    }
  }
```

I am not sure. But, I think you should install it first as `devDependencies` e.g. `yarn add -D url-loader`.

Comment: I'd already installed it and I tried. Still seem to get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`test: /\.(jpe|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,`

Try using this with your `file-loader` loader.
notice the **(?.*$|$)** instead of a plain **$**.

Comment: Tried it, as you said, with file-loader. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

{
          test:  /.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
          use:[{
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
          }]
        }

I loaded png with url-loader instead inside webpack. You need to rebuild webpack as well.

Comment: Please add an explanation.